# How to prevent automatically escaping in $this->db->update query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Update** function in Codeigniter automatically escapes my query.

My question is how can we prevent it?

As we can do same in select function with second parameter like `$this->db->select('col1,col2', FALSE);`

**EDIT:**
I have found this `$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);` but in this situation is I want to use an array instead of single parameter like `$this->db->set($array);` Again how to prevent escaping in this array situation?

Comment: Can you give an example where data is escaped, but should not be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I structured one solution, though its not a full version but it may help for other users.

In my case I wanted to escape just one column's value so I put that column in set function and all other array in update function like

```
$this->db->set("col1","value1",FALSE);
$this->db->update("tablenme",$allotherdataarray,$wherearray);
```

It worked for me.